# set null for total line with IgnoreUnrelatedimensions

Tags: ssas

Suppose, a measure group doesn't have any relation with Product dimension. We can easily make the report understandable by setting IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions = FALSE. But Total line is still showing the sum value. Is there any way so that i can set null for Total line too? I don't want to set the IsAggregatable = False of Product dimension as I need it for other measure groups. Any help?

Note: I want to have this effect in TOTAL line of any attribute of that dimension. Is there any generic way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the following into your calculation script:

```
SCOPE( { Root([Products]) } * MeasureGroupMeasures('name of your measure group'));
    This = NULL;
END SCOPE;
```

And if you want to have the same behavior for two more unrelated dimensions, say `DimA` and `DimB`, you would duplicate this block for each dimension like this:

```
SCOPE( { Root([DimA]) } * MeasureGroupMeasures('name of your measure group'));
    This = NULL;
END SCOPE;
SCOPE( { Root([DimB]) } * MeasureGroupMeasures('name of your measure group'));
    This = NULL;
END SCOPE;
```

You must keep these separate, as you want to have the value null for the `All` elements of `DimA`, irrespective if the `DimB` members are at the `All` level as well or not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have done according your way. But the measure group is getting affected by other dimensions too along with the product!!

Comment: @ShihabJamil Then repeat this statement block for all of these other dimensions.

Comment: This is the problem actually. I didn't want to write scope to handle every dimension :( . Isn't there any other way?

Comment: @ShihabJamil I am not aware of a simpler way. You can get to some point with `IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions`, but the rest is not intended to be standard behavior by the SSAS developers, hence needs some effort.

Comment: @FrankPI, Thanks a lot for your response. Will do in your way.

Comment: I have repeated this statement for other dimension. But still doesn't work. Can you please give an example considering a dimension relevant and another is irrelevant for a measure group. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ShihabJamil The only place where the dimension is relevant is as argument to the `Root` function. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: DimB is relevant to the measure group. So I want to have All value of DimB.
To have this I write:
SCOPE( { Root([DimB]) } * MeasureName);
    This = MeasureName;
END SCOPE;
But it won't work, because if I drag DimB on browser then "ALL" member is by default is selected and the scope for DimA is overridden hence showing null value for all members of DimB!

Comment: @ShihabJamil Now you are getting into some complexity: I see several approaches, and actually, I would have to experiment with these: Firstly, change the order of the statement blocks, possibly using the [`Freeze` statement][http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144733.aspx], and trying something like `SCOPE(Root([Products]) * [DimB].[Att1].[Att1].Members * [DimB].[Att2].[Att2].Members * MeasureGroupMeasures('name of your measure group')` for the setting to `null`. You would have to enumerate all attributes of DimB then. And for user hierarchies, I don't know without experiment as well.